# How to select list of next 30 dates for an input date parameter in oracle pl/sql or sql?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am trying to select next 30 dates for an input date parameter, i.e. if I enter 2/3/2016 I should be able to select next 30 days. Is there a way to do it in oracle ?
The expected output is : 
3/3/2016
4/3/2016
5/3/2016....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following, replacing `sysdate` with your start date:

```
select trunc(sysdate) + level
from dual
connect by level <= 30
```

This is based on hierarchical queries and on the fact that adding a number to a date means adding days.
`LEVEL` is a pseudo-column, disposable where you use `CONNECT BY`, which indicates, as it seems, the level in recursion; so, the first occurrence has level 1, then 2, and so on.

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm) are some more details on syntax and on the way this implements recursion.

Given that we have recursion on DUAL, with no conditions ( no `PRIOR` clause used), we use `LEVEL` both to sum 1, 2, 3 ( `+ LEVEL`) days and to limit the number of recursione levels we need ( `<=30`)